# VM won't let us allocation... bytes while downloading images

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am building a news paper app for that I need to show news paper images(epaper) in gallary view... I need to download about 100 images. for that I use asyncTask and for every download image I create new AsyncTask object and,when I am trying to download image and set into gallary I have the error in middle "VM won't let us allocation... bytes" and crash the app.

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> () {

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                    HttpGet httpRequest;
                    try {
                        httpRequest = new HttpGet(new URL(params[0]).toURI());
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity); 
                        InputStream is = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
                        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }/* catch (Error e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    if(result != null) {
                          img.setImageBitmap(ePaperInfo.getImgJpg1());
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }


            }
```

show the error in logcat:
[image]

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definetly not keep 100 Bitmaps on memory at the same time. You need to download only the Bitmaps needed and then call recycle() before downloading new Bitmaps.

Have a look at this exaple for the preferred way of doing what you want: [ImageDownloader](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/)

Comment: thanks for u'r replay, but I need to store those all images because I need to show all images in "galleryview".

Comment: Ok, then you should try implementing your adapter like the ImageDownloader example i posted above :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option for image loading that I use is [Prime](https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime), I use it in all of my projects and its pretty simple and efficient.